# Set http request message header ios

Tags: ios, wcf, nsmutableurlrequest

I have following code in my .net app.

```
MessageHeader<string> mhg = new MessageHeader<string>(SomeTicket);
     MessageHeader header = mhg.GetUntypedHeader("MessageName", "Namespace");
     OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
```

So i want to put the same message header from ios app by using NSMutableUrlRequest class, how to implement the same functionality from ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following instance methods of `NSMutableURLRequest` class. If you use first one, you have to pass dictionary with key-value pairs that you want to send in request headers. If you use second one, you can directly add headers one by one.

```
- (void)setAllHTTPHeaderFields:(NSDictionary *)headerFields

- (void)addValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field
```

For more details read [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: [request addValue:@"MessageName" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Namespace"];
correct?

Comment: [request addValue:@"some message" forHTTPHeaderField:@"MessageName"];

[request addValue:@"some namespace" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Namespace"];